# Facebook beta SDK for Unity 7.0.1 Android issue

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I'm testing the new Facebook SDK 7.0.1 beta, and seems that the .jar file is missing from the distribution. As soon as I try to use the SDK on Android, I get a java.lang.exception class not found com.facebook.blah.blah, and checking the package indeed, I cannot find a .jar file while it was included in the previous releases. Any hint  ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here. I added facebooksdk.jar from 6.2.2 just to test how far it could go. FB.init worked fine, but as expected other FB calls failed.

Comment: Please use the comment function to repond. Answers are something else.